# Put the record selection formula into another formula field

Tags: crystal-reports

The Record Selection Formula in Crystal may confuse end-users with no database knowledge. So I need to output a modified version so users can tell which documents were run and with which filters.

I would like to have a Formula Field called `ReadableSelectionFormula`, which outputs the original Record Selection formula with a few string replacements. For example, `{azw_Cus.code}` would become `CustomerID`

I can't find a way to include the Record Selection formula in another formula field. I can only drag and drop the field onto the designer somewhere. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this field into a formula by using the keyword `RecordSelection`.

Then nest `Replace()` statements to substitute the table names with user-friendly names:

```
REPLACE(RecordSelection, "{azw_Cus.code}", "CustomerID")
```